# Java paint not painting on top of previously called methods

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I have been unable to find an answer to this issue, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I am doing a class assignment where I have to make a scene using graphics. We've only had two lectures covering graphics so far, so I am hardly familiar. The issue is that she methods are not being painted in the preferred order. As you can see in the code to follow, I have two recursive methods making a sky and grass background/foreground. On top of those, I wish to have a cross (as well as many components thereafter granted I can get past this problem), but the cross does not appear as it should despite having that being the last method called within paint.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPicture extends JApplet
{
    public final int SIZE = 800;
    public final int DIST = 20;
    public Color bg1 = new Color(0, 200, 255);
    public Color bg2 = new Color(0, 175, 255);
    public Color grass1 = new Color(0, 220, 60);
    public Color grass2 = new Color(30, 255, 150);
    public Color brown = new Color(110, 80, 20);

    public void backgroundRec(int x, int y, int c, Graphics g)
    {
        if (c%2==0)
           g.setColor(bg1);
        else if (c%2==1)
           g.setColor(bg2);

        if (c < 40)
        {
            g.fillOval(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
            backgroundRec(x, y - DIST, c+1, g);
        }
    }

    public void foregroundRec(int x, int y, int c, Graphics g)
    {
        if (c%2==0)
           g.setColor(grass1);
        else if (c%2==1)
           g.setColor(grass2);

        if (x < SIZE/2)
        {
            g.fillRect(x, y, SIZE, DIST);
            foregroundRec(x, y + DIST, c+1, g);
        }
    }

    public void cross(int x, int y, Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(brown);
        g.fillRect(SIZE/2, SIZE/2, 45, 275);
        g.fillRect(SIZE/2-50, SIZE/2+45, 150, 45);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //backgroundRec(0, 0, 0, g);
        //foregroundRec(0, 400, 0, g);
        cross(SIZE/2, SIZE/2, g);
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you have a look at [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) and [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I'd then suggest having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is, you have a `StackOverflowException` in `foregroundRec`, because nothing is seems to be stopping it from updating, probably because you're not changing the value of `x`.

I "think" `foregroundRec(x, y + DIST, c + 1, g);` should be `foregroundRec(x + DIST, y + DIST, c + 1, g);` or something :P - but based on your code, `x` has to change

[image: Example]

You should also be calling `super.paint` before you do any of your own painting, this ensures that you don't end up with any weird paint artifacts

The other problem you're having is the fact that you're relying on the `SIZE` property, instead, you should be using `getWidth` or `getHeight` to determine what the actual size of the applet is

I'd also suggest having a look at:

- [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

## Updated

Okay, after going through a few iterations, what I actually think you're trying to do is...

```
if (y < SIZE) {
    g.fillRect(x, y, SIZE, DIST);
    foregroundRec(x, y + DIST, c + 1, g);
}
```